# Hack USB communication between device and application driver?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, usb

I have a USB device that communicates to my application using an application driver. I have to make an application that actually simulates this USB communication with App Driver so that I don't have to connect my device for USB communication.

In short, I have to hack USB communication between App Driver and the device using another application. It should be noted that data required for communication will be contained with this new application.

App Driver should not be tweaked in order to communicate with this proxy USB application. The driver is developed under some international standards and will not be changed for such applications.

Intended operating system will be Windows XP and Windows 7.

How can I simulate the USB device, so I can test the application without any real hardware?

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does "b/w" mean? Bandwidth? Black-and-white?

Comment: How does your application communicates with the driver?

Comment: 2. No its not homework...we have developed complete production line cum software solution for our customer. Since for our testing purpose we need this USB devices. Since devices are made on customer demand so we dont have enough device for testing purpose. So i was thinking to replace USB device with my proxy USB application so that

Comment: i dont need any device for testing purpose.(continuation to my previous comment)

Answer (score 2):

Hardware device emulation can be done at different levels. Lower level - better emulation, but usually low level emulation is difficult to develop. It can be also hardware emulation - hardware device which implements the same communication protocol like real device. But let's talk about software emulation.

Consider the following system structure: Hight level (UI) - hardware access Dll - driver - communication port (USB etc.) - hardware device. It is possible to emulate every level: from hardware device itself to hardware access Dll.

To emulate hardware device you should talk with hardware developers (not your case, I guess). You want to catch driver calls, to make this transparent to the whole software system. I think you have better chance to get information about this way on osronline - there are no driver experts on this site.

You can emulate the driver, providing another driver or even user-mode library, which exports DeviceIoControl, ReadFile, WriteFile. This is almost transparent to hardware access Dll - in emulation mode it should call emulated DeviceIoControl instead of Win32 DeviceIoControl.

Finally, you can emulate hardware access Dll, by providing emulation functions in Dll itself, or by writing another library with the same interface.

As you see, last two options are quite simple, and allow high-level application development without real device. Of course, the way you want to do this is most difficult, and will give the best results. Again, try to get more information about this in Windows drivers developers site.

It is also important, what part of this full chain (from UI to device) is yours, and what part is developed by your customer. If customer supplies hardware device, driver and hardware access Dll (SDK), it is quite enough for you to emulate this SDK, without writing complicated hooking stuff.

Comment: Closed - As you see, people here even don't understand what are you talking about. Wrong place to ask hardware and driver programming questions.